# How to make selected div on hover to change css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need little help, I'm new to JavaScript. I'm not sure how to fix the bug, currently, the code on hover is making the first box to display the title. But I want the title to be shown only on the chosen box. I thought in the for loop, the boxes[i] will make his first className[0] to display flex, but I guess it doesn't work that way. How can I fix this?

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-content-box");
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i ++){
    boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-content-title-box")[0].style.display = "flex";
    })
}
```

```css
.portfolio-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 2rem;

}

.portfolio-content-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 1rem;
    border-left:2px solid red;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s;
}
.portfolio-content-box:hover {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
.portfolio-content-img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.portfolio-content-title-box {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px RGBA(0,0,0,1);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
.portfolio-content-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
           <div id="portfolio-container">
             <div class="portfolio-content-box">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyn7ssQEg-KFcYHmAelMv3ro3wGqsMdmE8lw&usqp=CAU" class="portfolio-content-img"/>
                  <span class="portfolio-content-title-box">
                      <span class="portfolio-content-title">Title</span>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-content-box">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqg54h1j3ljdf73LUi1rAobP0jxmrbEd9W1A&usqp=CAU" class="portfolio-content-img"/>
                  <span class="portfolio-content-title-box">
                      <span class="portfolio-content-title">Title</span>
                 </span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use `JS`, but it can be done with pure `CSS`. You just need to target the title box when someone hovers the content box as below

```
.portfolio-content-box:hover>.portfolio-content-title-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

**Working Code**

```css
.portfolio-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.portfolio-content-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.portfolio-content-box:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.portfolio-content-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.portfolio-content-title-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.portfolio-content-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.portfolio-content-box:hover>.portfolio-content-title-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio-container">
  <div class="portfolio-content-box">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyn7ssQEg-KFcYHmAelMv3ro3wGqsMdmE8lw&usqp=CAU" class="portfolio-content-img" />
    <span class="portfolio-content-title-box">
                      <span class="portfolio-content-title">Title</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-content-box">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqg54h1j3ljdf73LUi1rAobP0jxmrbEd9W1A&usqp=CAU" class="portfolio-content-img" />
    <span class="portfolio-content-title-box">
                      <span class="portfolio-content-title">Title</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know I could do it with CSS only, thank you!